# Which short-cut is used to bring up this interface of ReSharper?

Tags: resharper

While I am watching the demo with the following link

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/demos/presentation/overview/refactorings/Refactor_this_demo.htm

I saw this screenshot
http://i52.tinypic.com/2cdfntc.jpg

I would like to know how to bring up this interface within resharper 5.0?

Comment: That looks like Control+Tab, which isn't even part of Resharper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is CTRL + TAB. Its a visual studio shortcut for the IDE Navigator. It is just showing open files and a preview of the content in them.

You can even modify some of the aspects of this window. Check [this](http://www.csharp411.com/disable-the-ctrltab-navigator-window-in-visual-studio-2008/).